# Is it safe to update postgres server to 9.5 with ubuntu automatic update

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.5 is out and Ubuntu has it in the update manager already.  I'm wondering though, is it safe to update that way?

Concerns/Questions:

Does it install 9.5 in addition to my already running 9.4 or replace it?

Does it migrate my data automatically?

Will there be downtime during the process?

Is it the same thing as running `pg_upgrade`

Am I missing anything else that I should be asking?

Comment: I'd try it in pre-production/test in a vm first. You will definitely have to restart Postgres

Comment: As long as you don't use any custom extension / tablespace, the script do all you need. Other configuration need testing. Tablespaces are not supported in the out-of-box script, but `pg_upgrade` is fine with that.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ but what will allowing the update manager to proceed do?  Does it install 9.5 alongside 9.4 and then do pg_upgrade and then remove 9.4.  Does it just install 9.5 alongside 9.4 and make me upgrade?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor , it install 9.5 alongside 9.4.  It will ask if you want it do upgrade for you. If you choose "yes", it will do pg_dumpall (default).
This is all configurable in postgresql-common package.